# AS3 | Devide to float number

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, numbers

Is there any way to devide by 10 and to check if the result is a float number?

My vars is:

```
var X:int=40;
var Y:Number=0;
//I want to Y get 4, 
//but when X is 45, Y get 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( X%10 == 0 )
    Y = X/10;
else
    Y = 0;
```

Comment: The same in one line: `Y = (X%10 == 0) ? X/10 : 0;` =)

Comment: Or one line but even shorter `Y = X%10 ? 0 : X/10;`  :>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var X:int = 45;
var Y:Number = (X / 10).toString().indexOf(".") == -1 ? X / 10 : 0;
```

Longer form:

```
var X:int = 45;
var Y:Number = 0;
var Z:String = (X / 10).toString(); 

if (Z.indexOf(".") == -1) {
    Y = X / 10;
} else {
    Y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i will use version of 3vilguy because is shorter.